# Como aumentar o número de floats no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática, criptografia

Fiz um programa que criptografa uma mensagem, mas ele não funciona quando a mensagem é grande pois o resultado fica grande.

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer o python me mostrar o resultado, não importando o tamanho da mensagem.

Código que possuo:

```
lista.append(float(msg[x-1])**(K_Primo*phi)+1)
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Comment: Você provalvelmente está esbarrando nos limites da sua plataforma, podendo checar com `sys.float_info`. Você pode tentar contornar esse problema usando o módulo `decimal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Python, números "float" usam por padrão os números em ponto flutuante disponíveis de forma mais direta na CPU- acho que em todas as plataformas em que Python é suportado, isso são floats de 64bit (IEEE 754).

No entanto, além de "ficarem grandes", números em ponto flutuante tem a característica de perderem precisão - muito antes de resultarem em um erro por "resultado muito grande".

Você leu um algoritmo teórico de criptografia em algum livro -mas aplicar isso em computação no mundo real não é só "digitar a fórmula" - há vários níveis de problemas numéricos de computação que tem que ser compreendidos - se o seu texto for completo o suficiente, e não só com o aspecto matemático teórico do algoritmo, vai ver que mais pra frente tem toda uma adaptação de espaços numéricos para que os cálculos possam ser feitos com números inteiros. No "mundo real" as bibliotecas de criptografia, desenvolvidas e mantidas ao longo de décadas por vários especialistas fazem essa parte.

Agora, só para você "ver funcionando", Python tem sim um pacote que permite números de ponto flutuante com precisão arbitrária que, possivelmente poderão atender a sua fórmula sem erro, só digitando do jeito que está.

Para isso, em vez do `float`, você vai usar a classe `decimal.Decimal`. Essa classe tem uma precisão padrão de 28 dígitos decimais - com certeza vai ser pouco para essa fórmula - mas talvez uns 2000 dígitos sejam o suficiente - o código abaixo vai alterar a precisão padrão do Decimal, e a partir daí você faz todas as suas operações (TODAS) usando essa classe em vez do float - e é possível que o algoritmo teórico funcione como está no livro. Para isso é necessário "converter" todo valor numérico que existe para um `Decimal`, com uma chamada a classe:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext, setcontext

ctx = getcontext()
ctx.prec = 2000
setcontext(ctx)

...
# seu código vai aqui - todos os números devem ser do tipo `a = Decimal(<numero>)` 
# - princpalmente o código que gera o `k_primo` e o `phi` que você usa na fórmula
...

lista.append(Decimal(msg[x-1])**(K_Primo * phi)+1)
```

(Além disso, claro, os itens da sua mensagem tem que ser numéricos - você pode converter entre números e caracters com a função `ord` (caracter -> número inteiro) e `chr` (numero -> caractere) ).

Na verdade, dependendo dos valores de "K_primo"  isso aí nao funciona nem com 2000 dígitos, nem com 2 milhões - nesse caso você tem que continuar até um capítulo mais avançado que pelo menos te de a fórmula usando exponenciação com módulo  -  por exemplo: 2 ** (1_000_000) já é um numero com 300 míl dígitos, que leva vários segundos para ser cálculado. E se você está falando de códigos ASCII nos valores da sua mensagem seria algo como "97 ** 1_000_000" - só para um caractere um número com ~2 milhões de dígitos
 e que leva minutos para ser calculado.
Por outro lado, um dos primeiros passos de "vamos tornar isso real" para criptografia é usar exponenciação com módulo nas fórmulas - https://pt.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation  - isso reduz o número de dígitos necessários de milhões para poucas dezenas e torna possível o uso de fórmulas com números tão pequenos quanto inteiros de 32 bits. (A função `pow` do Python faz exponenciação com módulo, bastando passar um terceiro parâmetro na chamada)

Quanto a tentar usar a fórmula original só com decimal.Decimal, só pra "ver funcionando", boa sorte - e lembre-se isso só é bom para demonstração - criptografia real é muito mais complexa, e é importantíssimo usar ferramentas que comprovadamente já funcionem. (em particular, este approach vai ser muito lento para qualquer aplicação real)

E, só para encerrar, o título da sua pergunta `Como aumentar o número de floats no python` sequer faz sentido -  o "número de floats possíveis" não tem como ser "aumentado" - a linguagem usa o padrão IEEE 754 (teoricamente, dependendo da arquitetura) - e você nunca teria memória para "criar um float de cada" para querer "aumentar o número deles". A formulação mais apropriada da pergunta seria "como aumentar a faixa numérica que pode ser representada por floats" - e, como respondido, para o tipo "float" isso é impossível - no entanto o tipo "decimal.Decimal" é flexível.

(e, claro também, o tamanho em dígitos dos números não tem nada a ver com o "tamanho da mensagem" como você implica no texto da pergunta, e sim com o código do caractere da mensagem que você está codificando)